# How does the git staging area store files?

Tags: git

I would like to understand what Git actually is storing when moving files into the "staging" state.

**Consider the following sequence:**

A new file is added and committed to the local repository:

```
touch file.txt
git add file.txt
git commit
```

I make changes to the file:

```
echo text1 > file.txt
git add file.txt
```

I then edit the file again, before committing it:

```
echo text2 > file.txt
```

A git status shows:

```
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       modified:   file.txt
#
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   file.txt
#
```

I then commit the file:

```
git commit file.txt
```

How is git able to handle staging the new, second update to *file.txt* without being told to?  The "status" output looks as if it would try to check the first revision in, but withhold the unstaged changes without checking them in.

Is there an implicit stage that is done in this case?

Comment: Note that the core of this question was actually answered in much more simpler way than in the answers here. See this Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27264847/1525602.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Think of Git as two things - commits (snapshots of files) and labels (branches, among other things).

Git actually creates a commit when you `git add`, not when you `git commit`. So when you executed `git add` on the changed file, it created a commit with those changes, and assigned the "staging" label to that particular commit.

When you changed the file again before executing `git commit`, it now has the "staged commit" (that hasn't had `git commit` executed on it yet), and the new changes to the file that has been neither added nor committed. That's how `git status` is able to show you both.

When you `git commit`, it is actually moving your current branch label to that particular commit (and removing the "staging" label), so the commit is no longer marked as "staging" but "master" (or whatever branch you're currently on).

Comment: The behavior I observe when I run the test described above is that it submits the unstaged contents of the file ("text2") into the repo as well.  Is this interpretation correct?  I would think it would submit the "staged" version of the file ("text1").  I am confirming this is what's in the repot by doing a "git checkout file.txt".

Comment: I just did a test but didn't get your results. `mkdir gittest` `cd gittest` `git init` `echo text 1 > test.txt` `git add .` `git commit -m 'Initial commit'` `echo text 2 > test.txt` `git add .` `echo text 3 > test.txt` At this point, there is the staged change ("text 2") and the unstaged change ("text 3"). Now, `git checkout test.txt` and `cat test.txt`. I get "text 2". The local change was discarded with the staged change.

Comment: I get the same results as your test sequence.  But if I do a `git commit` after the `echo text 3 > test.txt` step (similar to my steps in the original post), that's when I observe git implicitly staging the "text 3" content and submitting it to the repo.  For clarity, the sequence I do here is: `mkdir gittest` `cd gittest` `git init` `echo text 1 > test.txt` `git add .` `git commit -m 'Initial commit'` `echo text 2 > test.txt` `git add .` `echo text 3 > test.txt` `git commit -m 'new'` `git checkout test.txt` `cat test.txt`, resulting in an output of "text 3".

Comment: Um...are you absolutely sure? I just followed every step you listed exactly, and I ended up with "text 2" (which is the expected behavior of Git). Are you sure you didn't do a `git add` after changing the text to "text 3"? Be sure to note that when you `git add` and then change that file's contents, when you `git status`, it shows the staged changes and the unstaged changes. At that point, if you `git add`, it will update your staged changes with the new changes you made.

Comment: Ok - you're right.  I just re-ran this and after doing the "checkout", the file returned to "text 2".  I might have been issuing my checkout command incorrectly before.  Thanks for the second look!

Comment: This is not quite right, or one could say it's right but uses the word "commit" in a peculiar way.  Each file `git add`-ed creates a new "blob", not a new "commit", in git's terms.  `git commit` then writes "trees" based on the "index" (aka cache aka staging area) and, if all goes well, a "commit" that has the commit message text, the commit's parents, and the top-level "tree".  The "tree" gets you the "blobs" (plus subtrees that get more blobs, etc).

Comment: @torek +1 for an accurate and illuminating comment. My answer was more...metaphorical, to make it easy to understand. I highly borrowed from this excellent video: http://blip.tv/open-source-developers-conference/git-for-ages-4-and-up-4460524 I just wanted to express the more high-level concepts of what Git is doing behind-the-scenes.

Comment: @ilollar @torek Thanks all around - I found both of your explanations very enlightening.    I see that doing a `git add` adds what looks like the "blob" torek describes under `.git/objects/<hex>/<morehex>`.  This helped me to solidify my understanding that the `git add` is actually modifying the local repository, storing the staged contents of the file.

Answer (score 4):

`git commit <somefiles>` is equivalent to `git add <somefiles>` followed by `git commit`. If you just do `git commit`, git will commit all staged changes, but won't commit edits made since the last time you staged the file in question.