# Where Git staged files are stored?

Tags: git, github

I am not sure but this question popped up in my mind and started googling it. I found a lot of details about staging but failed to find where exactly git places `staged` files. I mean is there a file or folder that git uses to cache references to staged files and folders? Is yes which file it is?

Answer (score 12):

The staging happens inside `.git/index` and `.git/objects`. The former contains the paths and the latter contains the file content. Though these are all binary.

```
~/projects/bae/.git$ tree .
.
├── HEAD
├── config
├── description
├── hooks
│   ├── applypatch-msg.sample
│   ├── commit-msg.sample
│   ├── post-update.sample
│   ├── pre-applypatch.sample
│   ├── pre-commit.sample
│   ├── pre-push.sample
│   ├── pre-rebase.sample
│   ├── prepare-commit-msg.sample
│   └── update.sample
├── info
│   └── exclude
├── objects
│   ├── info
│   └── pack
└── refs
    ├── heads
    └── tags

8 directories, 13 files
~/projects/bae/.git$ cd ..
~/projects/bae$ touch test
~/projects/bae$ git add test 
~/projects/bae$ cd .git
~/projects/bae/.git$ tree
.
├── HEAD
├── config
├── description
├── hooks
│   ├── applypatch-msg.sample
│   ├── commit-msg.sample
│   ├── post-update.sample
│   ├── pre-applypatch.sample
│   ├── pre-commit.sample
│   ├── pre-push.sample
│   ├── pre-rebase.sample
│   ├── prepare-commit-msg.sample
│   └── update.sample
├── index                                           <-- NEW (contains paths)
├── info
│   └── exclude
├── objects
│   ├── e6
│   │   └── 9de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391  <-- NEW (contains file content)
│   ├── info
│   └── pack
└── refs
    ├── heads
    └── tags

9 directories, 15 files
~/projects/bae/.git$
```

Comment: Thanks but it seems like it does not store file name which is staged.

Comment: The index and cached files are binary.

Comment: Ok but when I do `git add .` then `git status` it shows me the list of files that are staged. Where is that list stored?

Comment: The paths themselves are in the .git/index file, albeit in binary format.

Comment: Try adding new files to the index, and then do a `cat .git/index`. You will see your file paths there.

Comment: @WillieWheeler `cat .git/index` will result in garbage since - as you already explained before - the content is binary. While you can directly print commit, tree and blob files (using `git cat-file`) I'm not aware of an alternative for the porcelain command `git status` to inspect the index.

Comment: There's garbage, but you can see the paths hiding inside the garbage. Here's a partial example: DIRC^@^@^@^B^@^@^@^DT|9\200^@^@^@^@T|9\200^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^D^AU\206\350^@^@\201\244^@^@^A\365^@^@^@^T^@^@^A\242\200&;2'R\204\310\362\
\215|XN\336\350^O\275\247\230v^@^Lbuild.gradle^@^@^@^@^@^@T|!\215^@^@^@^@T|!\215^@^@^@^@^A^@^@^D^AU\206\342^@^@\201\244^@^@^A\365^\
@^@^@^T^@^@\307J\311z\213\333\220\210\323p\332~\210xJz  ;\227^Z\242:^@!gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar

Comment: At any rate this is the answer to both the original question (where does Git store the files) and the subsequent one (where does Git store the list of filenames). :-)

Comment: I support the answer @WillieWheeler wrote. Do note that you can inspect the contents of the index with `git ls-files --stage`. In Willie's example, this would give: `100644 e69de29bb2d1d6434b8b29ae775ad8c2e48c5391 0       test` (test in this case is the filename of the object e69de2). See [git ls-files documentation](https://git-htmldocs.googlecode.com/git/git-ls-files.html) for more.